# Formatting txt in file_get_contents php

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this code to show txt file :

```
<textarea rows="11" cols="190">
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('./test.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
echo $file;
?>
</textarea>
```

the txt file look like this:
[image]

in one clean html file, it looked like this:
[image: the format is exactly like the txt file]

but when i paste it in laravel with portoadmin template, the txt format is broken and it looked like this:
[image: the format is broken]

What is wrong with that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your web-font into monospace-type font, like [this](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace). For example, if you render your `txt` file inside:

```
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Then make sure that `#container` element is using [monospace-type](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace) font. For instance:

```
#container {
    font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you, bro.